# Flashlight non responsive

Tags: google-project-tango

I have found that the flashlight is not readily accessible to the camera app or any other app for that matter on the project tango tablet. Can someone please point me to the source file for the flashlight. A java api reference would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Basically There is not driver for flash light in the Tango android system for normal camera API call, That is why flashlight is not accessible to the apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

flash light is disabled on tango devices. The flash light's software route is actually used by the IR projector.

Comment: How did that come to be?